# Using DOTENV correctly

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, dotenv

I have a db.js file like so

```
import "dotenv/config";

const devConfig = `"${process.env.PG_USER}://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}"`;

const prodConfig = process.env.DATABASE_URL;

const dbConnection =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? prodConfig : devConfig;

console.log(dbConnection);

export default dbConnection;
```

The `console.log` function correctly outputs the string that I need (which is `"postgres://postgres:learn@sql@localhost:5432/EPL"` in my case)

However, when I am trying to use import the `dbConnection` variable in another file, all I get is `"undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined:undefined/undefined"`.

The code of the file that I am trying to use the `dbConnection` variable is like below.

```
import pgPromise from "pg-promise";
import dbConnection from "../db.js";

const pgp = pgPromise({});
const db = pgp(dbConnection);
console.log(dbConnection);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What command are you running and what working directory are you running it from? `dotenv` looks for `.env` files in the CWD

Comment: I have `.env` file created in the WD where I have my `db.js`. I am running the 2nd file (where I call `dbConnection`) with `node fileName.js`. Is this a wrong this to do? I ask because my app(react+node) works fine but I still get the `undefined` string when I run `node fileName.js`.

Comment: Just to be clear `fileName.js` is being used in my app to connect to database & perform some queries & return the values which are then passed on to the Front End for rendering. The Front end seems to be getting the data (I had not seen this when I posted the question) but the `console.log` in the `fileName.js` just outputs `undefined` string when run standalone.

Comment: Like I said, `dotenv` looks for the `.env` file in the directory where you run the app from (the CWD). You can [customise the path](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path) if you want but usually you just want your `.env` file in the project root (along side `package.json`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `dotenv` looks for the `.env` file in the [**current working directory**](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/intro-to-earth-data-science/open-reproducible-science/bash/bash-commands-to-manage-directories-files/#print-current-working-directory-pwd), ie the directory you are in when running your app...

> [**Path**](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path)
> Default: `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`

If you run `node query.js`, then your CWD is whatever directory `query.js` lives in and `dotenv` will look for `.env` in **that directory**.

If you want to force `dotenv` to look in the same directory as your `db.js` file, the ES module version looks like this...

```js
// db.js
import { dirname, resolve } from "path";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config({
  path: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), ".env"),
});

// create and export your connection strings...
```

If you weren't using ES modules, it would look more like this

```js
const { resolve } = require("path");
require("dotenv").config({ path: resolve(__dirname, ".env") });
```

Comment: In my case I have 2 files `db.js` & `query.js`. `db.js` is the same working directory as `.env` file. However, `query.js` is not. The problem I have is that I export the `dbConnection` variable from my `db.js` file but it is printing as `"undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined:undefined/undefined"` in my `query.js` file. This happens when I run `query.js` file with `node query.js` command in the terminal

Comment: @moys ok. Does my answer not solve that for you? I think perhaps you still don't understand what a CWD is. I've tried to explain that in my answer

Comment: I do not even want to call `.env` file in my `query.js`. I just want to use the `dbConnection` variable. As I mentioned,  `query.js` file is getting the `dbConnection` variable & is making connection to the database & returning the results properly when I run the whole app. It is just that when i run the `query.js` alone with `node query.js` I get `"undefined://undefined:undefined@undefined:undefined/undefined"` as out put for `console.log(dbConnection);`. I cannot figure out the reason for this.

Comment: @moys have you even looked at my answer?

Comment: Saw the update now. Makes sense. Thanks. Up-Voted & accepted.

Comment: @moys It might also help to check for an error. Like `const { parsed, error } = dotenv.config({...}); if (error) throw error; if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') console.log(parsed)`

Comment: "If you run node query.js, then your CWD is whatever directory query.js lives in" this is wrong, the CWD is the directory from which you run the command

Comment: @Flame which in that example is the same directory as `query.js`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
//Write this as early as possible in your application
//This will use the local .env file.
dotenv.config();
```

Comment: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import