# Can I read .env into a variable instead of into process.env?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I would like to read the contents of my `.env` file into a variable other than `process.env` in Node.js. I am currently using the `dotenv` library but I am willing to use something else if anyone has alternatives to offer.

In my particular `.env`, username and password pairs will be stored on the server-side for authentication. I would like to read the file contents without overwriting `process.env` because there are other parts of my application that depend on values not being overwritten. I know that `override: false` is set by default in `dotenv`, so the values won't be overwritten, but I still need to access the new values. An example is `USERNAME` being set in one file to '`xterm`' for a third-party terminal login, but if a user's username in the dotenv file is '`USERNAME`' then I need to authenticate their password against the value instead of against '`xterm`', if that makes sense.

If I could aggregate the data from my `.env` file to something like `process.env.specialValues` and access the information via that nested property, that would be perfect.

Example of desired end behavior for clarity: `process.env.specialValues.USERNAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [parse()](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#parse) method to load the data into a variable

```js
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { parse } = require("dotenv");

const env = parse(readFileSync(resolve(process.cwd(), ".env")));
```

or if you're using ES modules

```js
import { readFileSync } from "node:fs";
import { resolve } from "node:path";
import { parse } from "dotenv";

const env = parse(readFileSync(resolve(process.cwd(), ".env")));
```

Comment: Awesome idea, thanks a ton! One note is that this is relative from the project root and not the file I am calling it from, so I have to use the path `src/server/auth/.env` instead. Any idea how to curtail this and use relative to the execution environment?

Comment: @AaronMeese I'm just using `process.cwd()` in exactly the same way `dotenv.config()` does. If you need to use a different path, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211712/283366)